# Where can i get the "admin-rest-client-0.10.0" java executable?

Tags: dependencies, kaa

I need to use "admin-rest-client" java executable to call the `KAA` rest API from my java project.

Is there any other external dependency required to add if I am using `admin-rest-client.jar`.

Comment: Any help from kaa team on this issue !

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here is a list for relese 0.9.0:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kaaproject.kaa.server.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>admin-rest-client</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kaaproject.kaa.server.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>dto</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kaaproject.kaa.server.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>utils</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kaaproject.avro-ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>shared</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```